# Firebase - How to get list of objects without using AngularFire

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular

Firebase - How to get list of objects without using AngularFire

I'm using typescript, angular2 and firebase.

I'm not using angularfire. I want to extract the data using their Api

My firebase url is /profiles

**This is the list of profiles I'm looking to extract:**

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a simple `value` event and re-assign the `array` every time the value changes.

[**JSBin Demo**](http://jsbin.com/fevozagebe/edit?js,output).

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://so-demo.firebaseio-demo.com/items');
ref.on('value', (snap) => {
  // snap.val() comes back as an object with keys
  // these keys need to be come "private" properties
  let data = snap.val();
  let dataWithKeys = Object.keys(data).map((key) => {
     var obj = data[key];
     obj._key = key;
     return obj;
  });
  console.log(dataWithKeys); // This is a synchronized array
});
```

Comment: Thanks David. Worked well